# MySQL query for booking. How to allow two reservations on the same date (check-in/check-out)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I'm trying to get all the room booked between two dates.
I'm using this query right now but I'm having an issue with it. I tried many thing, did a lot of search but after some hours I deciced to try to ask here for help.

```
SELECT 1 FROM reservations WHERE
checkin <= '$check_out' AND checkout >= '$check_in'
```

Let's say someone book 21st to 22nd.
He check-in on 21st at 4:00PM and check-out on 22nd at 12:00PM
The room is still free on 21st before 4:00PM
The room is still free on 22nd after 12:00PM

With this query, I can't book 20th to 21st
Check-in 20th at 4:00PM, check-out 21st at 12:00PM

I also can't book 22nd to 23rd.

Any idea how to adjust the query to reflect that reality?

There is also that query:

```
(checkin <= '$check_in' AND checkout >= '$check_in') OR
(checkin <= '$check_out' AND checkout >= '$check_out') OR
(checkin >= '$check_in' AND checkout <= '$check_out')
```

You can refer to this question, this is where I took my queries:
[Checking for date range conflicts in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914457/checking-for-date-range-conflicts-in-mysql)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853681/using-mysql-query-in-selecting-room-availability/23853910#23853910) helps

Comment: ... or this http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=577

Comment: It works. It works!!! I'm having trouble with the date logic. Thanks a lot @georstef.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@georstef posted me this link to see if it helps in the comment below my question: [Using MySQL query in selecting room availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853681/using-mysql-query-in-selecting-room-availability/23853910#23853910)

And it did!

The correct WHERE clause is now the following:

```
(checkin <= '$check_in' AND checkout >= '$check_in') OR
(checkin < '$check_out' AND checkout >= '$check_out') OR
(checkin >= '$check_in' AND checkout < '$check_out')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $AvailableWhere = array ('checkin <=' => $start, 'checkin <=' => $end, 'checkout >=' => $end, 'checkout >=' => $start, 'checkin >=' => $start AND 'checkout' <= $end);

$this->db->where($AvailableWhere);
```