# MySQL query for booking. Allow two reservations on the same date

Tags: php

I want user to create a booking system for hotel. For example:

Booking 1: 2019-08-01 - 2019-08-02
Booking 2: 2019-08-02 - 2019-08-03

The user should be able to create a booking concurrently. I try this solution

[MySQL query for booking. How to allow two reservations on the same date (check-in/check-out)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955445/mysql-query-for-booking-how-to-allow-two-reservations-on-the-same-date-check-i?lq=1)

but it is not working. My code are:

User can select date concurrently, so that there is no missing date from the list of booking

```
$exist=mysqli_query($samb,"SELECT * from tempahan where idbilik='$bilik' AND ((tarikh_masuk <= '$masuk' AND tarikh_keluar >= '$masuk') OR (tarikh_masuk < '$keluar' AND tarikh_keluar >= '$keluar') OR (tarikh_masuk >= '$masuk' AND tarikh_keluar < '$masuk'))") or die (mysqli_error($samb));
```

Problem happen when i run the following query:

```
insert into room_booked values (1, 102, '2014-06-01' , '2014-06-02');
insert into room_booked values (2, 102, '2014-06-02' , '2014-06-03');
insert into room_booked values (3, 102, '2014-06-05' , '2014-06-06');

SELECT
*
FROM
room_booked
WHERE
room_num = '102' AND

  (dor<='2014-06-06' and dco>='2014-06-06')
  or
  (dor<'2014-06-07' and dco>='2014-06-07')
  or
  (dor>='2014-06-06' and dco<'2014-06-07')
```

the result of the query should be 0, however the last data always shows.

Answer (score 0):

thanks. i finally understand what's wrong. it just a wrong logic. thanks for helps.

My solution:
    SELECT * from booking where room_id='$room' AND ((datein <= '$in' AND dateout > '$in') OR (datein < '$out' AND dateout >= '$out') OR(datein >= '$in' AND dateout < '$out'))");